# Multiple sets of radio buttons in a rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button

Is there a way to set up two groups of radio buttons in Rails? I can imagine you could put them into separate forms perhaps but is there a way to create two sets of radio buttons within one form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can create two different sets by simply using a different radio-button name:

```
radio_button_tag 'gender', 'male'
radio_button_tag 'gender', 'female'

radio_button_tag 'food', 'none'
radio_button_tag 'food', 'vegetarian'
radio_button_tag 'food', 'vegan'
```

This will result in params[:gender] being 'male' or 'female' and params[:food] being 'none', 'vegetarian' or 'vegan'. You can do the same thing with the radio_button function.

Answer (score 2):

Radio buttons with the same `name` attributes are grouped.
So make sure your Rails code uses the same names for the radio buttons within a group.

According to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-radio_button) the first parameter of the `radio_button` method is the name, so keep this parameter the same.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use radio_button_tag with simple loop.
Here you can map the selected value without having a corresponding model by using form_tag.

```html
<%= form_tag methods: :post do  %>
  <% (0..10).each do |value| %>
    <%= radio_button_tag 'store', value, :required => true %>
  <% end %>
  <%=  submit_tag 'submit' %>
<% end %>
```